# No intention to do something

Tags: negation, catenative-verbs

> Don't say that someone ‘has **no** intention **to** do’ something, but
> '...**of** doing something'.
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/EnglishUsage/intention

Why is it so? [*(Not) to intend to do something* is grammatical](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/intend).

Secondly, what about "**not (have) any** intention" ?

Comment: Obviously, this source of rules is defective.

Comment: It's not a matter of grammaticality - people say both 'to do' or 'of doing' and they both sound natural. Reading that style page... I can't make sense of it, the things it says are OK and the things it says are bad don't sound different to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this Google NGram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had%20no%20intention%20to%2Chad%20no%20intention%20of&year_start=1750&year_end=1850&corpus=26&smoothing=10) showing usage for 50 years before and after 1800...

[image]

That should be enough to suggest there's no particular "reason" why we favour ***of doing*** over ***to do*** today after ***intention***. It's just a matter of language changing over time, as variants become idiomatically established and/or fall out of favour.

But there's definitely a *general tendency* for English to rely more and more on prepositions. Which *might* be considered a factor here, given that ***to*** looks to me like just the "infinitive marker", whereas ***of*** is obviously a preposition.

Comment: complementary _not any intention **of/to**_ (? _"have any intention to_ yielded only one result")   https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=any+intention+to%2C+any+intention+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cany%20intention%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cany%20intention%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cany%20intention%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cany%20intention%20of%3B%2Cc0

Comment: The shift from ***to*** to ***of*** occurred earlier with ***any** intention* than it did with ***no** intention* - per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=any+intention+to%2Cany+intention+of&year_start=1720&year_end=1820&corpus=26&smoothing=10&case_insensitive=true), the "changeover point" for that one was around 1760. But I'd say it's all part of the same general trend.